# axios request on google cloud functions using express

Tags: ajax, rest, express, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a payment gateway rest API to retrieve a QR code.
It works well in my local with ajax but impossible to make it work with axios on a firebase cloud functions (express on nodejs).

My ajax code in my local:

```
var dataReq = {
      amount: '1',
      referenceNo: 'chelou',
      token:'myToken',
      payType: 'F',
      backgroundUrl: 'myBackgroundurl',
      customerEmail: 'dgdfgdgdgd'
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.gbprimepay.com/gbp/gateway/qrcode/text",
        data: dataReq,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        success: function(dataResp){
            console.log(dataResp)
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
          console.log(errMsg);
        }
    });
  });
```

My axios code in firebase cloud function:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.gbprimepay.com/gbp/gateway/qrcode/text',
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, 
    data: {
      amount: '1',
      referenceNo: 'chelou',
      token:'hW7RBDVpELvpxIJAxYf6AXl7ESXIWWOekGO/28aDCYkV7m07Fs26ko4QyROTFLNCZbRandtw5mxCgnQBtGdw5vYt5bkvmiZXi460Cc3yYWvNaE8LyEZJ1TdNJsX0poTwT9gb3hmy9JNdrxMB5HEwkjC9P18=',
      payType: 'F',
      backgroundUrl: 'https://us-central1-wyzauto.cloudfunctions.net/widgets/changeOrderStatus',
      customerEmail: 'dgdfgdgdgd'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.data)
    .then((responseFinal) => {
      return res.json(responseFinal);
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return res.json({result: error});
    })
  });
```

The ajax code is returning

```
{referenceNo: "chelou", qrcode: "00020101021230830016A00000067701011201150105560068…chelou530376454041.005802TH5910GBPrimePay6304192E", resultCode: "00", gbpReferenceNo: "gbp352913431029"}
```

The axios code is returning `{"resultCode":"90"}` it's not an error but for some reason the qr code is not being computed

Do you see anything wrong with my header or something like that?!?

Comment: Can you contact/research the nature of the REST service provider you are calling and find out from them what a "resultCode" of 90 means?  Under what circumstances might that be returned?  I think that will give you the clue you need.  I am NOT saying that this is the answer ... but a service provider could restrict client calls from certain domains.  Your service provider may restrict REST calls coming from GCP.

Comment: woshitom: Were you successful finding out about resultCode 90?